# Curl: (7) Failed to connect (docker)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, minikube

I have a problem executing a docker image. I'm running minikube on Ubuntu 22.04 (a VM over Windows 10).

Inside minikube, I've installed docker: `Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1`

When I run one of my images:
`sudo docker run -d -p 8000:5000 calculator`, I get the ID, however, by executing

`curl http://192.168.59.100:8000/add/3/2`, I get this error:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.59.100 port 8000 after 14 ms: Connection refused`

I got this IP by executing minikube ip. I've tried another solution from the forum where it said to execute `docker-machine ip default` and it still says to install docker when it is installed.

How can I execute this image? what I'm doing wrong. The link to the app deployment can be found here: https://ayushmaggo.hashnode.dev/dockerize-a-python-calculator-application

The files to build the docker are:
app.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello, welcome to the calculator app!"

@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<int:num2>')
def add(num1, num2):
    result = num1 + num2
    return str(result)

def subtract(num1, num2):
    result = num1 - num2
    return str(result)

def multiply(num1, num2):
    result = num1 * num2
    return str(result)

def division(num1, num2):
    result = num1 / num2
    return str(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

requirements.txt:

```
flask==3.0.0
```

Dockerfile:

```
 FROM python:3.9-slim
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY requirements.txt .
 RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 COPY app.py .
 CMD ["python”, “app.py”]
```

The commands to run it are:

1. `docker build -t calculator .`
2. `docker run -d -p 8000:5000 calculator`
3. `curl http://localhost:8000/add/3/2`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the application in the container actually listening on 0.0.0.0:5000?  Does this work in other Docker environments?  What's the main container process in the image; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks! @DavidMaze. I've updated the issue with a reproducible example.

Comment: As you've written it, your `CMD` has a mix of "straight" and "curly" quotes; it needs to have only "straight" quotes (like the one before `python`).  Can you check if you have this on your local system too?  The symptom here is that the container just wouldn't start up (it would try to run a shell command `["python”,`), and you'd see that in `docker ps` and `docker logs` output.

Comment: That was the solution! Thanks!